# How to get heuristic values of board

Tags: algorithm, minimax

I'm using the minimax algorithm for my 2 players custom board game. There's a White player and a Black player. Both players can move vertically and horizontally and to kill a pawn the enemy pawn has to be surrounded by the current player's pawns and vice versa

I want to get the heuristic value of a board. I was wondering how could I get this, so I came out with a plan of:

I count the number of pawns with `countNbPawnsLeft` - the more pawns, the better ( the score increments of 1 for each pawn alive)

Now where I'm having a problem is with my `canKillPawn` method/ For this method how do I evaluate the board? Do I check only for the pawns that changed places in the current board or do I have to check every pawns of my current player?

Comment: Why do you want to evaluate the board for the method `canKillPawn`? Does the evaluation result influence whether or not a pawn can be "killed"? I don't understand how that has any bearing on it. What does `canKillPawn` have to do with the title of your question? There are many open questions about the game. And when you mention methods (by name), it is only guessing for us to know what that method really is, without seeing any code...

Comment: Yes I check vertically and horizontally if there's a enemy pawn with no obstacle in between, is this not good?

Comment: Sure but that is not an evaluation function.

Comment: Really? So what is an evaluation function? Thank you btw

Comment: Really? So what is an evaluation function? Thank you btw

Comment: There is a difference between a function that determines whether a move captures a piece and a function that gives a score to a position. The latter is what an evaluation does.

Comment: But you should really add the rrelevant code to your question. It is quite vague what you are asking...